# How can I add a timer to my c++ console game

Tags: c++, timer, console

I'm currently working on a console game in which you should throw the ball out of the window to get points. I have a points counter, but I want a timer too.

Most of the timers on internet use the `sleep()` function but it stops the game so I can't use `sleep()`.

Can you give me a method with which I can print the time every second and restart it whenever the game triggers a new level?

```cpp
string FirstRenderer() {
string screen = "";

for (int i = 0; i <= ysize; i++) {
  // 1st Render Square
  for (int j = 0; j <= xsize; j++) {
    if (i == playery && j == playerx) {
      screen += " X";
    }
    else if (i == 0 || i == ysize || j == 0 || j == xsize) {
      screen += " o";
    }
    else if (i == engy && j == engx) {
      screen += " O";
    }
    else {
      bool temp = false;
      if (currentLevel == 1) {
        int len = sizeof(wallx1) / sizeof(wallx1[0]);
          for (int key = 0; key < len; key++) {
            if (j == wallx1[key] && i == wally1[key]) {
              temp = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (temp) {
          screen += " H";
        }
        else {
          screen += "  ";
        }
      }
      if (puanUp) {
        while (1) {
          srand(time(0));
          engx = rand() % (xsize - 1) + 1;
          engy = rand() % (ysize - 1) + 1;
          puanUp = false;
          if (engx != playerx || engy != playery) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      else if (engy == 0 || engy == ysize || engx == 0 || engx == xsize) {
        puan += 1;
        puanUp = true;
      }
    }
    screen += " ";
    // 2nd Render Square
    for (int j = 0; j <= xsize; j++) {
      if (i == playery2 && j == playerx2) {
        screen += " X";
      }
      else if (i == 0 || i == ysize || j == 0 || j == xsize) {
        screen += " o";
      }
      else if (i == engy2 && j == engx2) {
        screen += " O";
      }
      else {
        screen += "  ";
      }
      if (puanUp) {
        while (1) {
          srand(rand());
          engx2 = rand() % (xsize - 1) + 1;
          engy2 = rand() % (ysize - 1) + 1;
          puanUp = false;
          if (engx2 != playerx2 || engy2 != playery2) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      else if (engy2 == 0 || engy2 == ysize || engx2 == 0 || engx2 == xsize) {
        puan += 1;
        puanUp = true;
      }
      if (j == xsize) {
        screen += "\n";
      }
    }
  }
  return screen;
}
```

This is the function renders my game's screen.

Comment: Why not use something like [NCurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html) or something better than banging out huge strings?

Comment: Doing `+=` repeatedly is computationally far more expensive, especially since you have to repaint the entire screen instead of selective refresh to the screen buffer itself.

Comment: I am a bit new with string operations but I will take your advices thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to learn about game engine design and event loops before long. This kind of approach will hit a wall very quickly and you'll need an entirely different model to move past it.

Comment: I did a bit research but i didn't find a good resource that helps doing console games for beginners. Maybe you can give me resource and I would be appreciated.

Comment: The best way is to look at open-source examples and see how they've done it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>    
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    // TODO
    auto end = chrono::system_clock::now();

    chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    time_t end_time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);

    cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << endl;
}
```

this should be right.

Comment: For calculating time intervals, you should use `steady_clock` instead of `system_clock`.